# Use tab completion in bash script

Tags: bash, glob

I have several directories like `1-aaa/ 2-bbb/ 3-cde/`. There is only one directory for each number, so `echo "test" > 1<TAB>/test` is easy. I want to do

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    echo "test" > $i-(what to put here?)/test
done
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: asterisk? `*` See [Filename Expansion](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/run/ch04_08.htm)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you know the directories start with 1, 2, 3 but that you don't know the rest of the directory names?

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question itself. Instead, post an answer. (Yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer).) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with asterisk, like @banderlog013 proposed in comments, doesn't work directly.

I'm sure that it's possible to find some work-around to use asterisk-solution, but nevertheless you could use some additional step to find the directory :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3
do
    dir_name=$( find . -type d -name "$i-*" )
    echo "test" > $dir_name/test
done
```